# SpriteKit - add border with SKView

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

I was wondering how you could add a border using the SKView method, I tried initwithsize but did not like it.
My actual code for a border is:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeOfLoopRect:self.frame.size];

self.physicsBody.Dynamic = NO;
```

When I enter the code the border for the bottom works but the sides still allow objects to pass through them?
Is there a way to fix that? Or should I delete my code and try initwithsize?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

To get a little more familiar with physics bodies, you should read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:) on this issue to help you in the future.